# Prerequisites for Diophantine Approximation

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-approximation

I’m currently reading Fractal Geometry by Falconer to help learn some diophantine approximation theory, but would like to know if there are any supplementary texts which focus more specifically on diophantine approximation and number theory rather than fractals. I’m a 3rd year undergrad, so I’m looking for either an undergrad text or an easy graduate text. Thanks

Comment: For a really elementary beginning (for dinner table reading), look over Chapter 6: *The Approximation of Irrationals by Rationals* (pp. 81-102) of [**Numbers: Rational and Irrational**](http://users.auth.gr/siskakis/Niven-NumbersRationalAndIrrational.pdf) by Ivan Niven. After this, try [**Diophantine Approximations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486462676) by Ivan Niven (from the Preface: *A unique feature of this monograph is that continued fractions are not used.* **(continued)**

Comment: *This is a gain in that no space need be given over to their description, but a loss in that certain refinements appear out of reach without the continued fraction approach.*) To remedy this defect about avoiding continued fractions, perhaps look at Chapters X and XI in the classic [**An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0199219869) by Hardy and Wright, a book worth having around for other reasons as well.

Comment: That’s perfect, thank you!

Comment: While looking on one of my bookshelves for a certain book, I came across three really nice articles that I completely forgot about: In the book [**Kvant Selecta: Algebra and Analysis, I**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821810022) see the chapters *On Best Approximations. I* (pp. 27-35) AND *On Best Approximations. II* (pp. 37-47) AND *Rational Approximations and Transcendence* (pp. 65-69), all three by D. B. Fuchs and M. B. Fuchs.

Comment: I’ll be sure to check them out, that’s awesome, thanks so much again!